# Centering two buttons in android underneath a list view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-button

I have two `buttons` underneath a `listview` in my layout. The two `buttons` are inside a `linearlayout`. I tried changing the `gravity` of the `linearlayout` to **center** and changing `layout_centerInParent` to true, but that did not work.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add New"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete First"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_above="@id/add"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How do you want to center them margins from left and right???

Comment: `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` is applicable only for `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: I've tried each of these answers and for some reason I still can't get them centered. The linear layout code I posted above is below a listview and inside a linearlayout. Could that be my problem?

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Add New"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/delete"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Delete First"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: out put off top layout]

Comment: I tried this and for some reason I still can't get them centered. The linear layout code I posted above is below a listview and inside a linearlayout. Could that be my problem?

Comment: Tack screen shot from your xml code and preview  and add to question may we can answer your question . and draw wath you need and send it too

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give margin from left and right then you can do like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Add New"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Delete First"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_above="@id/add"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this and for some reason I still can't get them centered. The linear layout code I posted above is below a listview and inside a linearlayout. Could that be my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

To your LinearLayout.

Comment: I tried this and for some reason I still can't get them centered. The linear layout code I posted above is below a listview and inside a linearlayout. Could that be my problem?

Comment: You putted wrap_content to it LinaerLayout container width?

Answer (score 0):

make your root layout weightSum to 1 and list view layout_weight = 1

Answer (score 0):

If the LinearLayout was inside a RelativeLayout, try

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
```

Otherwise, use

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
```

Comment: I tried this and for some reason I still can't get them centered. The linear layout code I posted above is below a listview and inside a linearlayout. Could that be my problem?

Comment: Yes, try set the outer layout to RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Try my below code....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Add New" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Delete First" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Just small modification in your code....

Comment: I tried this and for some reason I still can't get them centered. The linear layout code I posted above is below a listview and inside a linearlayout. Could that be my problem?

Comment: Can you please post your whole code with ListView code?